# How can I change the dimensions of a xarray variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I have a gridded xarray dataset that looks like this:

```
print(ds)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (month: 12, isobaricInhPa: 37, latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)
Coordinates:
  * isobaricInhPa  (isobaricInhPa) float64 1e+03 975.0 950.0 ... 3.0 2.0 1.0
  * latitude       (latitude) float64 90.0 89.75 89.5 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * longitude      (longitude) float64 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.2 359.5 359.8
  * month          (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Data variables:
    h              (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 405, 720), meta=np.ndarray>
    speed          (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 405, 720), meta=np.ndarray>
    direction      (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 405, 720), meta=np.ndarray>
```

From this dataset, I extracted data for a series of points using:

```py
ds_volc = ds.sel(latitude=volc['Latitude'].values,longitude=volc['Longitude'].values, method='nearest', drop=True)
```

where `volc` is a Pandas DataFrame and `volc['Latitude'].values` and `volc['Longitude'].values` are vectors of lat/lon pairs for my 1431 points of interests.

```
print(ds_volc)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (month: 12, isobaricInhPa: 37, latitude: 1431, longitude: 1431)
Coordinates:
  * isobaricInhPa  (isobaricInhPa) float64 1e+03 975.0 950.0 ... 3.0 2.0 1.0
  * latitude       (latitude) float64 50.25 45.75 42.25 ... -56.0 -64.25 -62.0
  * longitude      (longitude) float64 6.75 3.0 2.5 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
  * month          (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
Data variables:
    h              (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 190, 1431), meta=np.ndarray>
    speed          (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 190, 1431), meta=np.ndarray>
    direction      (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 190, 1431), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Rather than using pairs of lat/lon coordinates, I need to add the *ID* of my points (called `Volcano Number`) as a new coordinate:

```py
ds_volc = ds_volc.assign_coords({'Volcano Number':volc['Volcano Number'].values})
```

which results in:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (month: 12, isobaricInhPa: 37, latitude: 1431, longitude: 1431, Volcano Number: 1431)
Coordinates:
  * isobaricInhPa   (isobaricInhPa) float64 1e+03 975.0 950.0 ... 3.0 2.0 1.0
  * latitude        (latitude) float64 50.25 45.75 42.25 ... -56.0 -64.25 -62.0
  * longitude       (longitude) float64 6.75 3.0 2.5 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
  * month           (month) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
  * Volcano Number  (Volcano Number) int64 210010 210020 ... 390829 390847
Data variables:
    h               (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 190, 1431), meta=np.ndarray>
    speed           (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 190, 1431), meta=np.ndarray>
    direction       (month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 19, 190, 1431), meta=np.ndarray>
```

### The question

Since I added the `Volcano Number` coordinate, the `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates (and dimensions) become obsolete and I need to reorganise the dimensions of the variables. I thought I could simply use `ds_volc.drop_dims(['latitude', 'longitude'])`, but that drops the associated variables. I have also tried `ds_volc.sel({'Volcano Number': 210010}, drop=True)`, but that returns a xarray.Dataset with 1431 longitude and 1431 latitude points.

Therefore, is there a way to somehow reshape the variables so their dimensions become `(month: 12, isobaricInhPa: 37, Volcano Number: 1431)` instead of `(month, isobaricInhPa, latitude, longitude)`, so as to return a xarray.Dataset of dimension `(month: 12, isobaricInhPa: 37)` when I query with `ds_volc.sel({'Volcano Number': 210010}, drop=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select a subset of a Dataset using numpy arrays or lists of lat/lons,  you subset the data in multiple dimensions *independently*. In other words, you're selecting all combinations of each of the lats with all of the lons - the result is still a world map, but with vertical and horizontal bands of data for each of the volcano coordinates. This is why you have 1,431 entries along both your latitude *and* longitude dimensions.

Instead, use a DataArray indexer to make use of xarray's [advanced indexing](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/user-guide/indexing.html#more-advanced-indexing):

```py
# set the column you would like as the DataFrame's index
volc = volc.set_index('Volcano Number')

# extract the data at each point, forming a new 1-D dimension 
# "Volcano Number" in place of "Latitude" and "Longitude"
ds_volc = ds.sel(
    latitude=volc['Latitude'].to_xarray(),
    longitude=volc['Longitude'].to_xarray(),
    method='nearest',
)
```

This will reshape the Dataset to conform to the shape of the `volc` DataFrame's index. The result will be indexed by the 1,431 volcanoes, rather than 1,431 lats and 1,431 lons.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for your help on my two problems! This full integration with Pandas is really cool...